# Will chain spray evaporate from its can when unused?

Tags: maintenance, chain, cleaning

My bike chain cleaning spray has evaporated from its can while I stored it in my room after having closed it normally. I have used it only four times. Actually about a half of the bottle should be there, but it has evaporated. Is this possible? How and why?

Comment: What is it, WD40?

Comment: Aerosol or squirty bottle? The former must be airtight, the latter doesn't need to be? Solvent or water-based? Could you smell it?

Comment: I don't think this is answerable without more information about what exactly this product was. In particular, what's your reason for believing that half the bottle should have been left? Maybe you used twice as much as you thought you did. For now, I'm voting to close this question as unclear but I will, of course, retract that vote if the question is clarified.

Comment: You need to describe this "spray" better.  What is the brand name?  What terms are on the container to describe it?  Is this an aerosol spray can or some sort of spray bottle?

Comment: Did it fall over at any point ?  I've found spray cans empty or clogged up if they were lying down for extended periods.

Comment: if it's an aerosol can and you've sprayed it upside down (part of the time) then it could be that the propellant gas is depleted which means the product (the chain spray itself) is still present in the can but it has no way to come out since there is no propellant gas left (when held upside down only the propellant gas leaves the spray can)